# compute sum of values associated with overlapping date ranges

Tags: postgresql, date-range

I have a simple table of date ranges each with an associated number of hours per week:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_ranges (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  rng daterange,
  hrs_per_week INT
 );
```

And some values from which I would like to compute (ie aggregate) the sum of hours per week for the overlapping/intersecting date ranges:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_ranges (rng, hrs_per_week) VALUES
   ('[2014-03-15, 2014-06-28]', 9),
   ('[2014-04-18, 2014-07-15]', 2),
   ('[2014-06-03, 2014-09-12]', 9),
   ('[2014-10-03, 2014-11-14]', 6);
```

Graphically (and hopefully this reveals more than it obscures), the solution looks as follows:

```
hrs/wk      T                                                 T`
  9         |  }-----|--------|-------->                      |
            |                                                 |
  2         |        }--------|--------|----->                |
            |                                                 |
  9         |                 }--------|------|---->          |
            |                                                 |
  6         |                                          }--->  |
            |                                                 |
 agg.hrs/wk     --9-- ---11--- ---20--- --11-- --9--    -6-
```

The final date range is deliberately non-contiguous with the other records but would still be included in the final recordset...
Clearly the solution entails generating 6 records from the original 4 and I'm pretty sure that the answer involves using window functions but I'm completely at a loss...

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt to solve this problem:

```
select y,
     sum( hrs_per_week )
from tmp_ranges t
join(
  select daterange( x,
         lead(x) over (order by x) ) As y
  from (
    select lower( rng ) As x
    from tmp_ranges
    union 
    select upper( rng )
    from tmp_ranges
    order by x
  ) y
) y
on t.rng && y.y
group by y
order by y
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ef6cb/13

The innermost subquery collects all boundary dates into one set using `union`, then sorts them.
Then the outer subquery builds new ranges from adjacent dates using `lead` function.
In the end, these new ranges are joined to the source table in the main query, aggregated, and `sum` is calculated.

---

EDIT
The `order by` clause in the innermost query is redundant and can be skipped, because `lead(x) over` caluse orders records by dates, and a resultset from the innermost subquery doesn't have to be sorted.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution, thank you (actually, my sincerest thanks(!), I'll be able to sleep tonight...).  I'd be fascinated to know if there are any other ways/techniques that could be employed to achieve the same effect.