# Sum of working days with date ranges from multiple records (overlapping)

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, overlap

suppose there are records as follows:

```
Employee_id, work_start_date, work_end_date

1, 01-jan-2014, 07-jan-2014
1, 03-jan-2014, 12-jan-2014
1, 23-jan-2014, 25-jan-2014
2, 15-jan-2014, 25-jan-2014
2, 07-jan-2014, 15-jan-2014
2, 09-jan-2014, 12-jan-2014
```

The requirement is to write an SQL select statment which would summarize the work days grouped by employee_id, but exclude the overlapped periods (meaning - take them into calculation only once).

The desired output would be:

```
Employee_id, worked_days

1, 13
2, 18
```

The calculations for working days in the date range are done like this:
If work_start_date = 5 and work_end_date = 9 then worked_days = 4 (9 - 5).

I could write a pl/sql function which solves this (manually iterating over the records and doing the calculation), but I'm sure it can be done using SQL for better performance.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't employee 1 be 15 = Jan 1-12 plus Jan 23-25?

Comment: Thanks Gordon. This can be interpreted in more than one way (inclusive/exclusive) so I made clear how the calculation is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slightly modified query from similar question: 

[compute sum of values associated with overlapping date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232796/compute-sum-of-values-associated-with-overlapping-date-ranges/22236718#22236718)

```
SELECT "Employee_id",
       SUM( "work_end_date" - "work_start_date" )
FROM(
  SELECT "Employee_id",
         "work_start_date" ,
         lead( "work_start_date" ) 
             over (Partition by "Employee_id"
                  Order by "Employee_id", "work_start_date" ) 
         As "work_end_date"
  FROM (
     SELECT "Employee_id", "work_start_date"
     FROM Table1
     UNION
     SELECT "Employee_id","work_end_date"
     FROM Table1
  ) x
) x
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t
   WHERE t."work_start_date" > x."work_end_date"
     AND t."work_end_date" > x."work_start_date"
      OR t."work_start_date" = x."work_start_date"
     AND t."work_end_date" =  x."work_end_date"
)
GROUP BY "Employee_id"
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4fcce/2

Comment: I like this one the most. Also, its great You provided a demo for the solution. Btw. what would the solution look like if I wanted to sumarize only the overlapped working days? For instance, the overlapping days for employee_id = 1 are 03-jan-2014 - 07-jan-2014 = 4 days...?

Comment: Is `lead()...` just creating adjacent segments between all dates?  If so, the `WHERE` checks each of these segments to see whether to include or exclude?  In that case, wouldn't every low segment get included if there was an unrelated higher range due to the first `AND` set being satisfied all the time?  test ranges: `'2016-01-01'` to `'2016-01-31'`, `'2016-02-10'` to `'2016-02-20'`, `'2016-03-01'` to `'2016-03-31'`   - Jan 31 to Feb 10 should be excluded but is included?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky problem.  For instance, you can't use `lag()`, because the overlapping period may not be the "previous" one.  Or different periods can start and or stop on the same day.

The idea is to reconstruct the periods.  How to do this?  Find the records where the periods start -- that is, there is no overlap with any other.  Then use this as a flag and count this flag cumulatively to count overlapping groups.  Then getting the working days is just aggregation from there:

```
with ps as (
      select e.*,
             (case when exists (select 1
                                from emps e2
                                where e2.employee_id = e.employee_id and
                                      e2.work_start_date <= e.work_start_date and
                                      e2.work_end_date >= e.work_end_date
                         )
                   then 0 else 1
            ) as IsPeriodStart
      from emps e
     )
select employee_id, sum(work_end_date - work_start_date) as Days_Worked
from (select employee_id, min(work_start_date) as work_start_date,
             max(work_end_date) as work_end_date
      from (select ps.*,
                   sum(IsPeriod_Start) over (partition by employee_id
                                             order by work_start_date
                                            ) as grp
            from ps 
           ) ps
      group by employee_id, grp
     ) ps
group by employee_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

date_tbl type

> ```
> create or replace package RG_TYPE is
>   type date_tbl is table of date;
> end;
> ```

function (result as a table with the dates between 2 parameters)

> ```
> create or replace function dates
> (
>     p_from date,
>     p_to date
> ) return rg_type.date_tbl pipelined
> is
>   l_idx date:=p_from;
> begin
>   loop
>     if l_idx>nvl(p_to,p_from) then
>       exit;
>     end if;
>     pipe row(l_idx);
>     l_idx:=l_idx+1;
>   end loop;
>   return;
> end;
> ```

SQL:

> ```
> select employee_id,sum(c)
> from
>   (select e.employee_id,d.column_value,count(distinct w.employee_id) as c
>   from   (select distinct employee_id from works) e,
>          table(dates((select min(work_start_date) as a from works),(select max(work_end_date) as b from works))) d,
>          works w
>   where e.employee_id=w.employee_id
>         and d.column_value>=w.work_start_date
>         and d.column_value<w.work_end_date
>   group by e.employee_id,d.column_value) Sub
> group by employee_id  
> order by 1,2
> ```