# Compute sum of hours/day with overlapping periods, SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a table with the start date(event.startdate), end date(event.enddate), and the hours/person (event.hrday) of an event. I have another table with weekdays listed which has another field for each person (calendar.name). I want to populate those columns with the total hours worked each day. I can't seem to figure out how to properly sum the hours if two events overlap in dates, I can only come up with a correct value for a single event in a time period.

I believe that in theory this question has the answer I need: [compute sum of values associated with overlapping date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232796/compute-sum-of-values-associated-with-overlapping-date-ranges/22236718#22236718)

But I am very new to SQL and I don't fundamentally understand the solution posted even after some additional research. I am using Access 2013. Apologies if this is a super elementary question, I was hoping what I wanted to do could be handled "visually" with Access...

What I Have: ("event" table)

```
Startdate | Enddate    |  Hrsday   | Name
 5/1/2015    5/12/2015     1.25      Joe
 5/7/2015    5/8/2015       8        Joe
```

What I'm looking for:("calendar" table, days already filled in first column)

```
Weekdays | Joe | name2 | name3 | ....
5/1/2015   1.25
5/4/2015   1.25
5/5/2015   1.25
5/6/2015   1.25
5/7/2015   9.25
5/8/2015   9.25
5/11/2015  1.25
5/12/2015  1.25
```

I've tried using the query builder within access to build an UPDATE query, but my result either does not appear at all (no updates, all null) or will only fill in one event with no overlaps. (5/1-5/12 all have 1.25).

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data, desired results, and any queries you have tried.

Comment: I tried to implement the solution I listed, but could not get it to work in any shape because I didn't really understand it and was just trying to force it to work. I managed to make a query within Access that appropriately finds work hours for a person and puts them in the appropriate column, but doesn't work for overlapping events.

Again, I think the linked solution is more or less what I need but I cannot understand it.

Comment: The solution you linked was for a different database and relies on features which are not supported in Access SQL.  You can't translate that other answer to Access SQL unless you are proficient with both SQL dialects.  I think you should show us sample data and then show us the result you want a query to give you from that sample data ... as Gordon suggested.

Comment: I see, that makes sense why it didn't work! I will update that here in a moment. Again, apologies for being vague.

Comment: What should happen if that second event gets rescheduled to start on 5/11/2015?  Does that mean you have to go back to the calendar table and subtract 8 hrs from Joe's stored values on 5/7 and 5/8?  And add 8 hrs to his stored values on 5/11 and 5/12?

Comment: Yes, that's the desired outcome. Ideally what I want to do is make a bar graph of this to measure each person's commitment over a period of time, if that sheds some light on the motive.

EDIT: And if it matters, I doubt there would ever be more than say, 10 events that would be in a single day, though I'd hate to put a strong upper bound on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to create a "date table" if you want to be able to achieve this sort of result in MS-Access (without using windowed functions).

Here is a quick example of how this might work in SQL Server, but only using syntax available to MS-Access (I hope).

```
--Load the test data into a table variable
DECLARE @event TABLE (
    [start_date] DATE,
    end_date DATE,
    hrsperday NUMERIC(19,2),
    name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @event SELECT '20150401', '20150412', 1.25, 'Joe';
INSERT INTO @event SELECT '20150407', '20150408', 8, 'Joe';

--Add some more test data, to make it more "interesting"
INSERT INTO @event SELECT '20150401', '20150405', 0.1, 'Bill';
INSERT INTO @event SELECT '20150401', '20150430', 7.5, 'Bill';
INSERT INTO @event SELECT '20150412', '20150415', 0.5, 'Bill';

--Make a date table, this creates one on the fly but wouldn't work in MS-Access
--I store a date for each day in 2015/Apr, obviously I would want more dates eventually
DECLARE @dates TABLE (
    [date] DATE);
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '20150401') AS [date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [date]) FROM cte WHERE [date] < '20150430')
INSERT INTO
    @dates
SELECT
    [date]
FROM
    cte OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

--Now the answer is trivial
SELECT
    e.name,
    d.[date],
    SUM(hrsperday) AS hrs
FROM
    @dates d
    LEFT JOIN @event e ON d.[date] BETWEEN e.[start_date] AND e.end_date
GROUP BY
    e.name,
    d.[date]
ORDER BY
    e.name,
    d.[date];

--Note the format you want, but a PIVOT would give you this
--(I don't think PIVOT is supported by MS-Access though)
```

Results for this are:

```
name    date    hrs
Bill    2015-04-01  7.60
Bill    2015-04-02  7.60
Bill    2015-04-03  7.60
Bill    2015-04-04  7.60
Bill    2015-04-05  7.60
Bill    2015-04-06  7.50
Bill    2015-04-07  7.50
Bill    2015-04-08  7.50
Bill    2015-04-09  7.50
Bill    2015-04-10  7.50
Bill    2015-04-11  7.50
Bill    2015-04-12  8.00
Bill    2015-04-13  8.00
Bill    2015-04-14  8.00
Bill    2015-04-15  8.00
Bill    2015-04-16  7.50
Bill    2015-04-17  7.50
Bill    2015-04-18  7.50
Bill    2015-04-19  7.50
Bill    2015-04-20  7.50
Bill    2015-04-21  7.50
Bill    2015-04-22  7.50
Bill    2015-04-23  7.50
Bill    2015-04-24  7.50
Bill    2015-04-25  7.50
Bill    2015-04-26  7.50
Bill    2015-04-27  7.50
Bill    2015-04-28  7.50
Bill    2015-04-29  7.50
Bill    2015-04-30  7.50
Joe 2015-04-01  1.25
Joe 2015-04-02  1.25
Joe 2015-04-03  1.25
Joe 2015-04-04  1.25
Joe 2015-04-05  1.25
Joe 2015-04-06  1.25
Joe 2015-04-07  9.25
Joe 2015-04-08  9.25
Joe 2015-04-09  1.25
Joe 2015-04-10  1.25
Joe 2015-04-11  1.25
Joe 2015-04-12  1.25
```